# htaccess parameters not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi there please if someone can help me, I want to do a redirection. I have created another cart system and i want to redirect a old zen to new ocart categories

example
`mywebsite.com/zen/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=16`

to 
`mywebsite.com/ocart/my_categorie`

I have SEO_Friendly URLS enabled in ocart

I do not even have a idea what to do, I have tried this but it does not work what can i do

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cPath=16$
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ http://mywebsite com/ocart/my_categories [L,R=301]
```

I would appreciate any and all help.

My setup, i have the root directory with a website in it that links to a subdirectory where the cart are located, but the root have now the old zen and the new ocart directories, google has indexed the zen one and i just want to redirect the zen categorie to the new ocart version. the root has it .htaccess file, and both the ocart and zen directory have there .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)products_id= [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ /ocart/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)cPath=16(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ /ocart/my_categories? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: does not work, ok let me explain what I have done, i have the main domain and 2 directories set up one for the old zen cart and one for the new ocart, main domain website has a website with just information that have a link to the ocart.

Comment: the old zen one is still indexed by google and i just want to make sure they land up in the ocart categorie i created, in the root i have a .htaccess file and in ocart and zen i have there individual .htaccess files, in the root i created one to rewrite the url from the www.domain to the non standard domain only name as that is how the lady had it indexed by google. i pasted this rewrite rule in the zen cart? was i correct in presuming that? but it did not work :(

Comment: Ure a star, seems apache took a while to update, can i ask a other question, is there a way of telling everything else should redirect to the ocart directory? for instance if there is a product that was index, for me to go and try to do all of them, to redirect the product_id version to the ocart directory

Comment: If you tell me a sample URL of `product_id version` I can suggest you something.

Comment: this is how it looks like    mywebsite.com/zen/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=16

Comment: Thank you you are a start. :) Thumbs UP for you!

Comment: Yet another successful rewrite assignment. :) +1 Do you test these rewrites somewhere, or feel so at home with them that you can just write-and-send?

Comment: I quickly test them on my local Apache server before posting the answers.